# How to evaluate the return type of a function dynamically?

Tags: typescript

I've got the following code:

```
// some interfaces to check
interface Car {
    name: string;
    color: string;
}

interface Bike {
    wheels: number;
}

// magic function that simplifies things
function getItems<Fn extends (...args: any[]) => ReturnType<Fn>>(  // <- this apparantly doesn't work (ReturnType<Fn>)
  getItemsFunc: Fn,
  item: ReturnType<Fn> | null
) {

  const getItem = () => {
    getItemsFunc().then((newItem) => (item = newItem));  // typescript complains here but should not complain here but in the last line
  };

   getItem();
}

// api call function that returns a promise. functions like this will be put into getItems()
function getCars(): Promise<Car[]> {
    // this would be an api call
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        resolve([{name: 'Mustang', color: 'red'}])
    })
}

// getItems will be used like this:
const cars: Car[] | null = null;
getItems(getCars, cars);

// i want typescript to complain about this:
const bikes: Bike[] | null = null;
getItems(getCars, bikes);  // <- getCars and bikes don't fit each other based on the types
```

How can I make typescript complain about the last line? But it should not complain about anything else.

I've put the code into the playground, see:
[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGcHsFsFNQJYDsAusBOAzAhgY1uKCpKLgBay4DWAUMmlnvAMLbqgDeNoPoS2cAFwQU6ZAHMA3N165IAG0jph4UROkBfGnVQYc%20UACEEVeF16gA7hVjzwwpAFdoAIwybtIUNGziEuUExHJFwUBEgkIjJsFAgEaAAHeQRMBAIoiXAaIJCwiNBxWBQASTRocAAeADFI2AAPNCQAE0IACgA6TrZxe1BsJABPAG0AXQBKUABeAD5QACUix3QkABUBhNhqpGnp1p4vCoBaDMJsBIS2fpR5AdAmyAIkAHJYyyUqUFaFlCXV9c2atMxjJCiUyuAqsFcMIagAaGQIMrCb6-NYbLazAA%20fEc8nkNAmXBkciQqgKRVKsGgU0%20ExmnBkPFBlPKkJCrTG7RQFCQrVaSFglhZdNmrURVJpAqFZTGY0k%20zAKH%204FwYgSsTkiXk2GQhAo6HgLkcsXAZEguKafEgGpgSR1kX1huNiEi3Pg2rJyQFMg00kZzLKHI8NC8ZwQpGweMCULyruisQNP2Wp1ACXQMAQ4Fg7WjuXCpNAyVMJysCCjblTzvoJADVPAHOyMfz5JQrHQ9bGwgACunoJnNm3RrNzLwvNzM1ZzfJLRX%20n0EuHcJH8RZE78%20ILQD2M1nWjlQs3WgaoPIAG6wQmMiygY8Kc%20tIYcfhCUBPACyjlU-XET1hpAUSjCE8BpNE8GjjFeGjAloIZgLW5SluW8CfrAlpFvA472DQJJkku7bCIOIygNiThRpMOJ4tI8H1qCbbgH%20eHgHKnhgOGlhXEQyqqgg6pECQmp2sgfQuOasSYYI2ERGSLgmAQwjGKYozERR8iSri8hURS4KtLRbD0aAMmmEx8qgAcxy6e2fTNAZsmEPczyxKksSwHgZCgNa%20oGdgWaWvkbqcRsWRAA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
// magic function that simplifies things
function getItems<T>(  // <- this apparantly doesn't work (ReturnType<Fn>)
  getItemsFunc: () => Promise<T[]>,
  item: T[] | null
) {

  const getItem = () => {
    getItemsFunc().then((newItem) => (item = newItem));  // typescript complains here but should not complain here but in the last line
  };

   getItem();
}

// i want typescript to complain about this:
const bikes: Bike[] | null = null;
getItems<Bike>(getCars, bikes);  // <- ts complains
```

Also, typescript doesn't know what type to use for generics unless you specify, as in `getItems<Bike>(...)`

Comment: I looks right, but Typescript doesn't complain about the last line. The problem seems to be that bikes = null at the beginning. If i do bikes = [] it works. Is it even possible to have it complain, while bikes = null?

Comment: Does it work if you `let bikes` instead of `const bikes` ?

Comment: I think I've forgotten <Bike> next to getItems. It seems to work. Do you know of any functionality to infer T? So  I don't have to write <Bike> and typescript just gets it from the function?